# Meaning of the verb "set" (in Mathematics)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a math book And I have come across this verb (set) many times in this book. I have searched all online dictionaries But because this verb has a special meaning (I think so) in mathematics, I could not find a suitable meaning for it. The closest meaning I could find was:''to cause sb/sth to be in a particular state.''the verb ''set'' is used in expressions like these:

> setting t=0
>
> setting [image]
>
> setting [image]
>
> setting [image]

and so forth.I am finishing this book and I managed to write down the meaning of almost all the words below them, but I still can not understand the meaning of this verb.I would be very happy if you could explain the exact meaning to me. I am Iranian and English is not my mother tongue. Please do not close this topic again This is really important to me.

Comment: I am familiar with 'set theory' from my school days. But I do not know of 'setting' in math. Have you asked your classmates or teacher? (I assume this is for school)

Comment: No its not related to sets. Its a verb and I guess it must mean "assuming or letting t=0 ، x=... " but I'm not sure

Comment: It means "**assign**." "Assigning 0 to t..." or "Assigning t to 0..."

Comment: Arashrostrami, the reason your question was closed and downvoted is because you showed no evidence of research – specifically, looking up "set" in a dictionary – or, alternatively, because you're not a fluent English speaker or Star Trek fan ("set phasers to stun") and you would be better served by our other site [ell.se]. You can find out more about what we're looking for on EL&U by reading [ask] and taking the short but informative **EL&U [Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than immediately quoting a lot of mathematical examples, let me use one of the conventional definitions of **set**. I suggest the following is the most relevant:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set)
> set:
> to cause something or someone to be in the stated condition or situation

Let's apply this to your first example of "setting t=0"

This type of statement is normally used after a discussion of an idea or process involving a variable, in this case *t*, probably time.

In a mathematical development of the idea, we often need to consider how the process develops after some initial time, or we may be interested in how the process developed at previous times. In either case we could do the job in terms of time measured after or before any arbitrary instant (noon, 2 o'clock, and so forth) but it is usually most convenient or meaningful to imagine the process before or after time zero.

Hence we have the usage "setting t=0", meaning that we put *t* in the state or condition that it is zero, and that the temporal development of the process is thereafter defined at previous (negative *t*) or subsequent (positive *t*) times *t*.

The same analysis applies to your other examples. It is a commonplace and conventional usage in mathematics or physics and tells us that some condition or state is to be placed on or imagined for the object of the phrase.